# Disable Windows Key + Up Arrow

Tags: windows-10

Is there any way to disable the Winkey+Up and Winkey+Down hotkeys?

I do not want to disable the Windows Key entirely. I quite like some of the default hotkeys that use it, such as Winkey+R.

I have already turned off "Snap Windows" in Settings-> System -> Multitasking. However, this has only disabled the Winkey+Left and Winkey+Right hotkeys.

I've been trying to use AutoHotKey to accomplish this, but it does not work. For example, if I use

```
#G::send,^!+G
```

When I press **Win + G** that still briefly brings up the window that that hotkey is tied to by default. Those windows then close, and a new Office window opens with a message "We've run into an error."

Answer (score 0):

There are two programs that can help you to turn off specific Windows hotkeys, they are SharpKeys and AutoHotkey.

SharpKeys allow you to turn off a specific hotkey or adjust it to another key as you want. Meanwhile, AutoHotKey will help you to turn off a specific hotkey by adding a script.

Take a look at the following article:

https://www.howtogeek.com/194811/how-to-prevent-the-windows-key-alttab-and-sticky-keys-from-ruining-your-gaming/

Comment: I've been trying to use AutoHotKey to accomplish this, but it does not work. I edited my question to show what I tried.